# Bluetooth is not working 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have tried all possible solutions, The only mistake I have made is to turn Bluetooth off. and Now its totally disabled and I can't even click on it. I have tried all possible solutions.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-10-25 16:53:26 IST; 2min 20s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 20974 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─20974 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 bluetoothd[20974]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 bluetoothd[20974]: Parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf failed: Key file does n
اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 bluetoothd[20974]: Starting SDP server
اکتوبر 25 16:53:26 ijunaid8989 bluetoothd[20974]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

also updated to latest version

```
junaid@ijunaid8989:~/Downloads$ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1
junaid@ijunaid8989:~/Downloads$
```

Still, results are the same.

[image]

I turned it off from top right panel and I am unable to take a screenshot of it. where you have Bluetooth Icon, turn off and bluetooth settings button.

```
junaid@ijunaid8989:~/nuxtjs-blog$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
junaid@ijunaid8989:~/nuxtjs-blog$
```

and Also I am using Inspiron 13 7000 Dell, I had a device connected with bluetooth and I just turned the bluetooth all of a sudden from top right navigation pannel in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It seems either don't have bluetooth hardware in your computer, or it doesn't get detected. I suggest you google to verify that you DO have the hardware and also try to find out whether you have the correct driver installed if anything similar is needed.

Comment: @Junaid Farooq Please explain what you did to turn it off; in software or with a switch? Please provide the make of your PC, that would help, along with the model number from the sticker on the back or bottom which shows the model number. Only that model number is useful to us; model numbers on top, the screen bezel, or keyboard surround are not helpful. Also please run `rfkill list all` and add its result to the question as well. Please provide that to us by clicking [edit] then adding the information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Updated the question :) using edit